# How can I prune discord users without a specific role?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm the owner of a medium-sized discord server that tends to get raided a lot, so to set up protection I added a "member" role and locked all the channels except "role request" (where they can react to a message to gain roles), "rules" (lists the rules) and "welcome".
In the "welcome" channel, a bot instructs users to tag our "staff" role, at which point a staff member will come on, make sure they aren't going to flood us with propaganda, and give them a "member" role. Once they are a member, they can access the full server.

My problem is that many people have neglected to tag staff and are now completely idle. I cannot prune them as they have roles, just not the member role. I would like to kick everyone on the server who does NOT have the member role. Is this possible?
Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Iterate through the members of the server, check for the role, and kick them if they don't have it

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def purge_members(ctx):
    for member in ctx.message.server.members:
        if not get(member.roles, name='member'):
            await bot.kick(member)
```